# Electron testing - WebdriverIO switch between the devtools window and main app window

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, electron, webdriver-io

We need to test [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) App.
We are using [Spectron](https://github.com/electron/spectron) which is using ChromeDriver and [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/api.html) (Selenium 2.0 bindings for NodeJS).

**Problem:** Our application starts with open dev tools window than main application window is shown. Webdriver connects to dev tools window instead of the main window. We are unable to switch to main window.

Example code:

```
var app = new Application({
    path: cfg.pathToElectron,
    args: [cfg.pathToSA]
});

app.start().then(function(){
    app.client // <- this is dev tools window instead of main window

    // this closes the dev tools which is ok but we need to switch to main window
    app.client.close();

    // things like this doesn't help 
    app.client.execute('xxx.getCurrentWindow().closeDevTools()');
});
```

**Any ideas how to switch from dev tools to main window?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You know that feeling when you ask a question and than immediately find the answer?*

The solution is to call [`windowByindex()`](https://github.com/electron/spectron#clientwindowbyindexindex) from the Spectron API. You need to call the API functions from the Spectron for this, not the functions from the [Webdriver](http://webdriver.io/api.html).

So solution to our problem is:

```
app.start().then(function(){
    app.client.windowByIndex(1);    
});
```

Comment: I am quite confused about the difference between the api and Spectron and WebdriverIO, what are the commons between them? When should I use which?

Comment: If you want to control something which is Electron specific you call Spectron API https://github.com/electron/spectron#application-api but if it's regular feature which would be the same as if the app would be running in the browser you would call WebdriverIO. In 99% of cases you will be calling Webdriver API.